# Cannot resolve rails deadlock in background job

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, deadlock, database-deadlocks

I am developing rails application and have a deadlock problem.
Let me assume that I have two models: `User` and `Book`.
Since User can have many books, the association is like that

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :books
end

class Book < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :user
end
```

Next, I prepare background job in sidekiq.
this job is like that:

```
def perform
  user.books.find_by(genre_id: XXX).update(status: "done")
  (...)
  user.books.update_all(status: "undone")
end
```

And when I perform this in two (or more) proceses, I often deadlock Error

```
Mysql2::Error: Deadlock found when trying to get lock; try restarting transaction
```

I omitted the code between two update methods, but I am sure that these two methods cause deadlock Error.

why do this happen?

I copy the result when I did `SHOW ENGINE INNODB STATUS;`

```
        *** (1) TRANSACTION:
        TRANSACTION 4613489, ACTIVE 1 sec fetching rows
        mysql tables in use 1, locked 1
        LOCK WAIT 13 lock struct(s), heap size 1136, 1036 row lock(s), undo log entries 9
        MySQL thread id 81, OS thread handle 140180891285248, query id 54793 172.18.0.9 root updating
        UPDATE `books` SET `books`.`status` = "complete" WHERE `books`.`user_id` = 1075
        
    
    ** (1) HOLDS THE LOCK(S):
    RECORD LOCKS space id 61012 page no 7 n bits 352 index PRIMARY of table `app`.`books` trx id 4613489 lock_mode X
    Record lock, heap no 1 PHYSICAL RECORD: n_fields 1; compact format; info bits 0
     0: len 8; hex 73757072656d756d; asc supremum;;
    
    Record lock, heap no 2 PHYSICAL RECORD: n_fields 10; compact format; info bits 0
     0: len 8; hex 8000000000000001; asc         ;;
     1: len 6; hex 00000011058b; asc       ;;
     2: len 7; hex 0200000148159b; asc     H  ;;
     3: len 4; hex 80000001; asc     ;;
     4: len 4; hex 80000001; asc     ;;
     5: len 4; hex 80000001; asc     ;;
     6: len 4; hex 80000000; asc     ;;
     7: SQL NULL;
     8: len 8; hex 99aa46aba207a8cc; asc   F     ;;
     9: len 8; hex 99aa46aba207a8cc; asc   F     ;;
    
    (...)

*** (1) WAITING FOR THIS LOCK TO BE GRANTED:
RECORD LOCKS space id 61012 page no 15 n bits 256 index PRIMARY of table `app`.`books` trx id 4613489 lock_mode X waiting
Record lock, heap no 187 PHYSICAL RECORD: n_fields 10; compact format; info bits 0
 0: len 8; hex 800000000000040b; asc         ;;
 1: len 6; hex 000000466570; asc    Fep;;
 2: len 7; hex 020000023f1b5c; asc     ? \;;
 3: len 4; hex 80000001; asc     ;;
 4: len 4; hex 80000438; asc    8;;
 5: len 4; hex 80000001; asc     ;;
 6: len 4; hex 80000001; asc     ;;
 7: SQL NULL;
 8: len 8; hex 99aa837d9c0d03f4; asc    }    ;;
 9: len 8; hex 99aa837db50d03df; asc    }    ;;

        
        *** (2) TRANSACTION:
        TRANSACTION 4613488, ACTIVE 1 sec starting index read
        mysql tables in use 1, locked 1
        LOCK WAIT 9 lock struct(s), heap size 1136, 6 row lock(s), undo log entries 12
        MySQL thread id 80, OS thread handle 140180893349632, query id 54817 172.18.0.9 root updating
        UPDATE `books` SET `books`.`status` = "complete" WHERE `books`.`user_id` = 1073
        
        *** (2) HOLDS THE LOCK(S):
        RECORD LOCKS space id 61012 page no 15 n bits 256 index PRIMARY of table `app`.`books` trx id 4613488 lock_mode X locks rec but not gap
        Record lock, heap no 187 PHYSICAL RECORD: n_fields 10; compact format; info bits 0
         0: len 8; hex 800000000000040b; asc         ;;
         1: len 6; hex 000000466570; asc    Fep;;
         2: len 7; hex 020000023f1b5c; asc     ? \;;
         3: len 4; hex 80000001; asc     ;;
         4: len 4; hex 80000438; asc    8;;
         5: len 4; hex 80000001; asc     ;;
         6: len 4; hex 80000001; asc     ;;
         7: SQL NULL;
         8: len 8; hex 99aa837d9c0d03f4; asc    }    ;;
         9: len 8; hex 99aa837db50d03df; asc    }    ;;
    
    *** (2) WAITING FOR THIS LOCK TO BE GRANTED:
    RECORD LOCKS space id 61012 page no 7 n bits 352 index PRIMARY of table `app`.`books` trx id 4613488 lock_mode X waiting
    Record lock, heap no 2 PHYSICAL RECORD: n_fields 10; compact format; info bits 0
     0: len 8; hex 8000000000000001; asc         ;;
     1: len 6; hex 00000011058b; asc       ;;
     2: len 7; hex 0200000148159b; asc     H  ;;
     3: len 4; hex 80000001; asc     ;;
     4: len 4; hex 80000001; asc     ;;
     5: len 4; hex 80000001; asc     ;;
     6: len 4; hex 80000000; asc     ;;
     7: SQL NULL;
     8: len 8; hex 99aa46aba207a8cc; asc   F     ;;
     9: len 8; hex 99aa46aba207a8cc; asc   F     ;;
```